# Maven dependency is being excluded from my shaded jar incorrectly

Tags: maven, keycloak

I have a dependency that I want to be included in my shaded jar

I have even added it in includes

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.shade.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>software.amazon.awssdk:*</include>
                        <include>org.keycloak.keycloak-services:*</include>
                        <include>org.keycloak.authorization.client:*</include>
                        <include>org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But yet I am seeing

[INFO] Excluding org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:13.0.1 from the shaded jar.

This is a problem as I then get Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/authorization/client/Configuration at runtime

How do I force it to be included?

Comment: Which version of maven-shade-plugin are you using? Furthermore a full pom file would be helpful...

Comment: Im using version 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<include>org.keycloak:*</include>
```

because the groupId of the jar `org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:13.0.1` is `org.keycloak`

According to [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) document:

> Artifacts are denoted by a composite identifier of the form groupId:artifactId[[:type]:classifier].